# .map returns length of the resulting arrays for each iteration?

Tags: javascript

```
var king = [1,2,3,4];
var kong = [55,77];
var thor = king.map(function(num) { return num + 1 });
var pan = king.map(function(num) { return kong.push(num) });

console.log(kong); // [55, 77, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(thor); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(pan); // [3, 4, 5, 6] ??
```

I thought I understood what .map was doing, but after playing around with it, I found a result that confused me. For the result of console.log(pan), I was expecting:

```
[[55, 77, 1], [55, 77, 1, 2], [55, 77, 1, 2, 3], [55, 77, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

However, the result is:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

It looks like it's returning the length of each resulting array? Confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

You have an array of lengths.

Here's an implementation of what you seem to want (not changing kong because it always feels better to be functional):

```
var pan = king.reduce(function(arr, num) {
  arr.push((arr[arr.length-1]||kong).concat(num));
  return arr
}, []);
```

Comment: Ah. It was push() that I didn't understand correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat()` instead.

```js
var king = [1,2,3,4];
var kong = [55,77];
var pan = king.map(function(num) { return kong = kong.concat(num) });

console.log(pan);
```

Answer (score 2):

`push` returns array length. So you have array of lengths.

You can achieve what you expect by:

```
var pan = king.map(function(num) { 
    kong.push(num);
    return kong.slice(); // create array copy!
});
```

And do not forget to copy array, otherwise you will get an array with same array as elements.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that is non destructive to `kong`

```js
var king = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var kong = [55, 77];

var pan = king.map(function(_, i) {
  return kong.concat(king.slice(0, i + 1));
});
console.log(pan);
```

Answer (score 0):

map applys the function you specify to each of the elements in the array. So the answers it is giving you are correct for the first array

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to manually push the elements inside a map. The map operation applies your function on every element of the array and returns a new array based on results.

To be honest that's the whole purpose of the map method.